# Does adding simple script tasks to SSIS packages drastically reduce performance?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, etl

I am creating an SSIS package to import CSV file data into a SQL Server table.
Some of the rows in the CSV files will have missing values.

For example, if a row has the format: **value1,value2,value3** and value2 is missing,
then it will render as: **value1,,value3** in the csv file.

When the above happens (value2 is missing) in my SSIS package, I want NULL to go into the receiving SQL Server column that would hold value2.

I understand that I can add a "Script" task to my SSIS package to apply this rule.  However, I'm concerned that this will drastically reduce the performance of my SSIS package.  I'm not an expert on the inner workings of SSIS/SQL Server, but I'm concerned that this script will cause my script to lose "BULK INSERT" capabilities (and other efficiencies) since the script will have to inspect every row and apply the changes as needed.

Can anyone confirm if adding such a script will cause major performance impacts?  Or does the SSIS/SQL-Server engine run the script on every row and then bulk-insert?  Is there another way I can apply this rule without taking a performance hit?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can use script task when required. Script task will be executed only once for each execution of the whole package not for every row. For every row there is another component called script component. When the other regular SSIS tasks are not enough to achieve what you want you can surely use script component. I don't believe it is a performance killer unless you implement it badly.

Secondly, this particular requirement you can simply use Flat File Source task to import your csv file. It will put the value NULL when there is no value. I'm considering this is a valid csv value and each row has correct number of comma for every fields (total field - 1 actually) even if value is empty or null for some fields.